# How do I get the accessibility value of a React Native view in an Android app?

Tags: react-native, android-view, android-espresso

I'm writing automated tests for an Android app that uses React Native to render most UI elements. As React Native views [don't support resource IDs](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/9777) like Android views do, I've been using [accessibility labels](https://medium.com/@csovis/running-automated-ui-tests-on-react-native-with-espresso-2e296d81c342) for automation purposes.

However, I also need to access the accessibility *values* of some views. For example, some of our code looks like this:

`<View accessibilityLabel = "some_label" accessibilityValue = "some_value" />`

I can get the accessibility *label* using `withContentDescription()` in Espresso and `getContentDescription()` with standard Android code. However, it's not clear how to do the same for accessibility values.

Thanks in advance!